# NextJS 13: Conditional Intercepted route and Normal route

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am working on a nextjs 13.4 app router where I have an intercepted route(@modal) on clicking a card and on reload the page the normal page will get displayed. But on a certain condition, I need to show the normal page instead of the modal on click as well. How can I achieve this in app router.

Grid card with a click handler that opens a route in modal(Intercepted route). On certain condition should open normal route instead of a modal